# Android Studio how to automatically update data that is stored in Firestore Real Time Database

Tags: android

is it possible for android to automatically update the data that is stored in real time database? For example, the data that is gonna be stored in my firebase real time database is going to be constantly changing within seconds because it is connected to a back-end system that triggers its change. Could it be done that every time the data has changed, the textView in my application that shows that data gets updated every time as well ? For now, I have a button that updates the data on click, but is it possible to update it automatically without a button? My code looks like this for now :

```
a = findViewById(R.id.insidetempView);
    b = findViewById(R.id.filterView);
    c = findViewById(R.id.humiditytextView);
    d = findViewById(R.id.CO2textView);
    Button saveButton = findViewById(R.id.numbersButton);

    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            reff = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Numbers");
            reff.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    String CO2 = snapshot.child("CO2").getValue().toString();
                    String filter = snapshot.child("Filter").getValue().toString();
                    String humidity = snapshot.child("Inside_humidity").getValue().toString();
                    String temp = snapshot.child("Inside_temperature").getValue().toString();
                    a.setText(temp);
                    b.setText(filter);
                    c.setText(humidity);
                    d.setText(CO2);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This blog post should provide you with the solution you need go through it and you will be able to do what you want https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html

it has information on using android  Architecture Components with Firebase Realtime Database. and when you observe `LiveData` you can implement all changes instantly